# Add an external domain to a Google App Engine app (different from the host)

Tags: google-app-engine

My app (http://videonot.es) is hosted on Google App Engine, this account is owned by an other Google Apps domain (unishared.com) for several reasons.

I want to add my second domain (videonot.es) to this app. 
When I go to "Application settings" in the app dashboard, "Add domain" > "videonot.es" I'm redirected to my Gapps panel where I have to accept terms and conditions to add my app to this domain.
When I accept this terms, I have an error message : "An error occurred, please try again later".

Now I have to redirect from my second domain to the first via a DNS record, how can I make it properly works?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182452

Comment: Got it, thanks for pointing me here. I've deleted my second Google Apps account, successfully added it as an alias of my primary but still can't add this domain to AppEngine. It works now! Just to precise: have to add the new URL via Google apps admin and not from App Engine dashboard, this does not work.